# How to get response message? NodeJs, ReactJs, Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, postman

Back end is written with nodejs, there is some validations and after a bad validation i should get a response status with a message - 'msg':

[image]

When I do an axios post method from front end I get:
[image]

But with postman I get(I want this result in front end):

[image]

I want to get in front end the same as postman a msg property not a error response.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch method for error handling. A demo is as follow

```
 try{
    const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/register');
    console.log(data);
 }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for Fetch request, you can change it for Axios Accordingly

```
const res = await fetch("/request-path", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.text().then(function (text) { // This line will get the msg
        console.log(text)   //here you can access it
      });
    });
```